# Can Master also be configured as memory-optimized?

Tags: configuration, error-log, sql-server-2022

I am currently discovering the new SQL Server 2022 features and found this message in the error log

> cleanup of stale db entries skipped because master db is not memory optimized

At first I thought this message was due to a non-memory-optimized TempDB, but after enabling MO tempdb (and a restart) I still get this message.

My friend google doesn't provide me with an answer. Is this a future extension?